# MiniZinc CSP into JSON - iteration in arrays workaround javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, minizinc

I use the node.js module "Governify CSP Tools" in order to solve a CSP problem. 
Following the instructions of how I should define an array from the CSP model schema (https://www.npmjs.com/package/governify-csp-tools) I have tried multiple representations in JSON but still getting error:

> array: Ingredient_1= [30 ,     30 ,    30,     15,     15,15,  5 ,
>   5 ,     5 ,     1]; 
>        ^  Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting [

My javascript code is:

```
var Reasoner = require("governify-csp-tools").Reasoner;



var cspModel = {
    "parameters":[

      {
          "id":"x",
          "type":"int",
          "value":"0"
      },
      {
          "id":"y",
          "type":"int",
          "value":"7"
      },
      {
          "id":"z",
          "type":"int",
          "value":"0"
      },
      {
          "id":"k",
          "type":"int",
          "value":"4"
      },
      { 
          "id":"Ingredient_1",
          "type":"array",

          "value":"[30 ,    30 ,    30, 15, 15,15,  5 , 5 , 5 , 1]",
      },
      {
          "id":"Ingredient_2",
          "type":"array",
          "value":"[3 , 7 , 12, 3 , 7 , 12, 3 , 7 , 12, 3 ]"
      },
      {
          "id":"Ingredient_3",
          "type":"array",

          "value":"[0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ]"
      },
      {
          "id":"Ingredient_4",
          "type":"array",
          "value":"[0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ]"
      },
      ],
    "variables": [
      {
        "id": "occur",
        "type": "int",
        "range": {
          "min": "1",
          "max": "10"
        }

      }

    ],
    "constraints": [
      {
        "id": "C1",
        "expression": "x == 0 -> forall (i in occur) (Ingredient_4 [i]= 0)"
      },
      {
        "id": "C2",
        "expression": "y=7 \\/ y=6 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_1 [i]=30 )"
      },
      {
          "id": "C3",
          "expression": "y==1 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_1 [i]=0 )"
        },
      {
          "id": "C4",
          "expression": "z==5 \\/ z==6 \\/ z==7  ->forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_4[i] !=0) "
      },
      {
          "id": "C5",
          "expression": "k==7 \\/ k==6 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_2 [i] =12)"
      },
      {
          "id": "C6",
          "expression": "k==5 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_2 [i] =7)"
      },
      {
          "id": "C7",
          "expression": "k==4 \\/ k==3  -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_2 [i] !=0)"
      },
    ],
    "goal": "satisfy"
  };

  // Configure the CSP reasoner
  var reasoner = new Reasoner({
      type: 'local', // type value also can be 'api' or 'docker'
      folder: 'csp_files' // name of the folder which stores .mzn, .fzn and .ozn temporary files

  });


  console.log("solving model");
  // Solve CSP
  reasoner.solve(cspModel, (err, stdout, stderr, isSatisfiable) => {

      if (err) {
          // manage error
          console.log("model error");

      } else {

          console.log(stdout);
          console.log(isSatisfiable);

      }
      console.log("model solved");

  });
```

is there any workaround I can define the array outside the JSON schema and call it  later on again inside the JSON schema to make the iterations where is needed such as:

```
"id": "C2",
        "expression": "y=7 \\/ y=6 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_1 [i]=30 )"
```

the executable .mzn represantation which I try to translate into JSON is:

```
int: x = 0; % x-parameter
int: y = 7; % y-parameter
int: z = 0; % z-parameter
int: k = 4; % k-parameter
array[1..10] of int: Ingredient_1 = [30 ,   30 ,    30, 15, 15,15,  5 , 5 , 5 , 1]; % Ingredient_1-parameter
array [1..10] of int : Ingredient_2 = [3 ,  7 , 12, 3 , 7 , 12, 3 , 7 , 12, 3 ]; % Ingredient_2-parameter
array [1..10] of int: Ingredient_3 = [0   , 0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ]; % Ingredient_3-parameter
array[1..10] of int: Ingredient_4 = [0   ,  0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ,   0   ]; % Ingredient_4-parameter
var set of  1..10: occur; % occur-variable
constraint x == 0 -> forall (i in occur) (Ingredient_4 [i]= 0); % C1-constraint
constraint y=7 \/ y=6 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_1 [i]=30 ); % C2-constraint
constraint y==1 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_1 [i]=0 ); % C3-constraint
constraint z==5 \/ z==6 \/ z==7  ->forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_4[i] !=0) ; % C4-constraint
constraint k==7 \/ k==6 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_2 [i] =12); % C5-constraint
constraint k==5 -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_2 [i] =7); % C6-constraint
constraint k==4 \/ k==3  -> forall (i in occur)(Ingredient_2 [i] !=0); % C7-constraint
solve satisfy; % goal
```

The question is following the JSON schema expressed on YAML and specifically this:

> title: 'CSP model JSON schema' type: 'object' properties:
>   parameters:
>       type: 'array'
>       items:
>         type: 'object'
>         properties:
>           id:

from the https://www.npmjs.com/package/governify-csp-tools, how can I represent in JSON this:

```
array[1..10] of int: Ingredient_1 = [30 ,   30 ,    30, 15, 15,15,  5 , 5 , 5 , 1];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have no experience with the javascript library you are using. It seems that it is using the field `type` without any conversion in the generated MiniZinc model.

As your MiniZinc model suggests, the correct way to declare an array is:

```
array[1..10] of int: Ingredient_1 = [30, 30, 30, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 1];
```

However, the generated MiniZinc model contains:

```
array: Ingredient_1 = [30, 30, 30, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 1];
```

**This suggest that the `type` field should not contain `array`, but `array[1..10] of int`.**

(Similar problems probably occur for the other arrays in the JSON format)

Comment: thank you for the comment! I believe this is the problem as well, but have not found a way to represent it into JSON so that to get the correct output: array[1..10] of int: Ingredient_1 = [30, 30, 30, 15, 15, 15, 5, 5, 5, 1]; Another way of workaround I have thought of, was to represent the problem with int, instead of arrays  to get rid of these errors,(it seems much easier) but the Gecode solver does not seem to solve it so I have to find a solution with that JSON represantation.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced this

```
"type":"array"
```

with this

```
"type":"array [1..10] of int"
```

and it generated the right .mzn